# Uploading Videos using Jive REST API

Tags: rest, jive

I am using Jive REST API to upload video. Based on the Jive REST documentation, I am following the process to submit the request.

POST:

```
https://{Community_Url}/api/core/v3/contents
```

Body (JSON format):

```
{ 
    "content": {  
       "type": "text/html",  
       "text": "<body><p>Upload a file using API </p></body>"  
       },  
    "subject": "Test Video Aug 21 - 2",  
    "visibility": "place",  
    "categories" : [ "support" ],
    "tags" : ["exit"],
    "type": "video",
    "attachments" : [{  
       "name" : "dolbycanyon.mp4",  
       "url" : "http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/dolbycanyon.mp4",  
       "doUpload" : "true"}]
```

}

Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: "Basic {username and password}"
```

Unfortunately the response I am getting is a server issue.

Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>

    <head>

        <title>System Error</title>

        <style>

    body {

    font-family : arial, helvetica, sans-serif;

    font-size: 81.25%;

}

    td, th, p, div, span, li, a { font-size : 1em; }

    h1 { font-size : 1.72em; }

    code {

        font-family : courier new, monospace;

        font-size : .8em;

}}

    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="jive-header">

            <h1>System Error</h1>

        </div>

        <p>

We're sorry but a serious error has occurred in the system.

        </body>

    </html>
```

Somehow, the **"type":"video"** in JSON request is not working. Can anybody provide some suggestions how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

To upload videos in Jive you need to use a different endpoint. Please check the API documentation below:

https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/cloud/rest/VideoService.html#uploadVideo(MultipartBody)

If you want to upload the video as a file (i.e. not to be rendered by Jive) you need to use the type "file":

https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/cloud/rest/FileEntity.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did tried both the options but it seems, it is not working as expected. For the multipartbody request, I have tried to upload the video and json request as two separate files as form-data, but still finding the same issue

Comment: Which version of Jive are you using? Do you have access to the logs? Can you see any error when you post your requests? Thanks.

Comment: That's a good point Andre. Unfortunately, I am using an external Api call due to which I don't have access to the logs. Let me see if I can get some information on it. Thanks

Comment: Here is the exception that I found looking into the logs. "com.jivesoftware.community.media.video.providers.ProviderCommunicationException: Error reading video properties"